# SQL Server 2008 - error using OVER with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This query works flawless at SQL Server 2014 (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/19de4/1), but I'm having problems with 2008 version, complains "Incorrect syntax near 'order'. What am I missing?

```
CREATE TABLE t (id BIGINT, cliente VARCHAR(100), vendas FLOAT);

INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, 'vitor', 234.3);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (2, 'emerson', 456.2);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (3, 'thiago', 6789.3);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (4, 'john', 5423.0);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (5, 'fulano', 3467.8);

SELECT *, CASE WHEN vendas_agrupadas <= 0.7 THEN 'A' ELSE 
(CASE WHEN vendas_agrupadas <= 0.9 THEN 'B' ELSE 'C' END) END 
AS "Grupo ABC" FROM (
  SELECT *, SUM(vendas) OVER (ORDER BY vendas desc)
  /(SUM(vendas) OVER()) AS vendas_agrupadas FROM t) asdf;
```

Comment: Adding the data into SQL Fiddler made it really easy to work with - thanks!

Comment: @CindyH a shame it hasn't the SQL Server 2008 version, but the site is great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 doesn't support cumulative sums directly.  The following version with a subquery should do what you want:

```
SELECT *,
       (CASE WHEN vendas_agrupadas <= 0.7 THEN 'A' 
             WHEN vendas_agrupadas <= 0.9 THEN 'B'
             ELSE 'C'
        END) as "Grupo ABC"
FROM (SELECT *,
             (SELECT SUM(vendas)
              FROM t t2
              WHERE t2.vendas >= t.vendas 
             ) / (SUM(vendas) OVER()) AS vendas_agrupadas
      FROM t
     ) asdf;
```

Some notes:

- This may not produce exactly the same results if there are duplicated values of `vendas`.
- `case` can accept multiple `when`, so you don't need nested `case` statements.

Comment: I tested also with duplicated values of vendas and it seems to work well. Thanks very much.